# GoogleMaps Flutter Plugin MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin and when I change screen I receive a lot of exceptions in the console:

```
E/flutter (17053): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method map#update on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_2)
E/flutter (17053): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (17053): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17053):
E/flutter (17053): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method markers#update on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_2)
E/flutter (17053): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (17053): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17053):
E/flutter (17053): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method polygons#update on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_2)
```

My GoogleMap widget looks like this:

```
    String id = "id";
    BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon; // this is set and visible


    GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: _markers,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(<some-lat>, <some-long>),
            zoom: 15,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _googleMapController.complete(controller);
                setState(() {
                    _markers.add(Marker(
                        markerId:
                            MarkerId(this.id),
                        position: LatLng(<some-lat>, <some-long>),
                        icon: pinLocationIcon,
                        )
                    );
                });
           },
   ),
```

Is there a fix for these errors or am I using the `Widget` incorrectly?

EDIT 1:

This issue has existed for a while and happens every time I run the app. I have done multiple `flutter clean` `flutter pub get` cycles while developing and it still persists. It does not stop overall functionality of the app but is still annoying and blocking while developing. It also only occurs on Android.

Answer (score -1):

You should follow few steps:

1. flutter clean
2. Pub get
3. Run your application

Comment: I have done this several times. This issue has existed for a while through multiple iterations of my app. It doesn't stop the functionality of the app but still is annoying.

Comment: flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org - open this folder and search for the plugin that you are using and delete that plugin from pub.dartlang.org folder and again try to run - flutter clean and flutter pub get. hope this helps

Comment: still cant run.. i did all of it.. my team doesnt have this exception why only me though